# PutExtra doesn't work on the retriever side

Tags: android

I want to sent intent from one first activity to another.

The first activity sends an intent to the second activity in order to create a new AlertDialog, receive  a number from the user and send the number back to the first activity, that's where putExtra data to failed.

The code of the first activity: GuessItActivity.java

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GuessItActivity.this,
                        AlertDialogMessage.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION);
                
                intent.putExtra("data1", 15);
                startActivityForResult(
                        intent,
                        getResources().getInteger(
                                R.integer.ALERT_DIALOG_MESSAGE));
```

on the retriever side , e.g the second activity side on  AlertDialogMessage.java

```
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // "OK" button pressed
                            int userGuess = Integer.parseInt(input
                                    .getText().toString());
                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                            if (intent == null)
                                return;

                            int data1 = intent.getIntExtra("data1", -1);
                            if (data1 != 15 )
                                return; // data1 ==15 
                            
                            intent.putExtra("data2", 25);           
                            if (getParent() == null) {
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                            } else {
                                getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,
                                        intent);
                            }
                            finish();
```

The first activity side: back to GuessItActivity.java

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == getResources().getInteger(
            R.integer.ALERT_DIALOG_MESSAGE)) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent==null)
                return; 


              Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extra != null) {
                int _data1 = extra.getInt("data1");
                int _data2 = extra.getInt("data2");
            }
               // extra  == null , what am I doing wrong  ? 

            int data1 = intent.getIntExtra("data1",-1);
            int data2 = intent.getIntExtra("data2",-1);
            if ((data1==-1)&&(data1==-1))
                return;
```

The problem is , that I receive data1 and data2 equal to -1.

I'd like to receive the data the I put on the second activity. e.g data1 == 15 and data2 == 25

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Bundle extra=data.getExtras();
```

Insted of

```
Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 int a=extras.getInt("data1");
```

Comment: extras == null , do you know what should I do next ?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
  int data1,data2;
  Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extra!=null){
  data1=extra.getInt("data1");
  data2=extra.getInt("data2");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm having a progress. extra == null , do you know what should I do next ?

Comment: @TripleS i don't understand what you want to say

Comment: your intuition was good. when I'm trying  your code I receive that extra == null and can't continue. on the other hand . I don't know why  I receive a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

in onActivityResult you are not suppposed to call

```
intent = getIntent();
```

directly you have got the

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

where data corresponds to the data sent from the alert box activity. Just directly calling

```
data.getIntExtra("data2", -1);
```

should do. Hope I was clear enough.